# Quick favorites dosen't show up in 3D viewport

Tags: shortcut, quick-favorites

so I switched to Blender lately and watched tons of tutorials.
and I quickly discovered that my "Quick Favorites" did not function correctly in the 3D viewport like the others in tutorials.

it simply doesn't respond in the 3D viewport but only to the MENU bar, which is the area that I marked in Red color.

pay attention to the keystroke below, you can see that I was continually pressing "Q", but the "quick favorites" only popped up when the mouse in the MENU and Tool Bar area, not the 3Dviewport.

[image]

i tried couple of versions (3.3/3.4/3.5alpha)in Blender but the issue remains the same. does anyone know why??

this really bothers me, and it's odd that I found no similar issue discussion online.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Favourites menu needs to be populated with functions of your choice. You need to add operators to it by right-clicking on something and choosing Add to Quick Favourites:

[image]

The menu is also context sensitive, so it will be different in different contexts like in different editors or modes (like Object, Edit, Sculpt and other).

You can see, change or restore the default hotkey(<kbd>Q</kbd>) for it in the User Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd>-><kbd>P</kbd>), Keymap tab if you enter Q into Key-binding mode search:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply :)
sorry I didn't make it clear before,
I am aware of how "Quick Favorites" works.
but the actual question is that it won't pop up when the mouse is INSIDE the 3Dviewport.

I recorded a Gif screenshot that indicates the issue more clearly

Comment: Did you check if the keymap is OK? You could temporarily rename Blender's user preferences folder (`%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4`) and start Blender so it starts with 'factory' settings to see if the problem is with your user preferences. I think there might be something wrong with the keymap, maybe there is some conflicting shortcut set for Q in some context. Some addon might be interfering as well.